# DateListPlot to DateListHistogram

Tags: histograms, plot-themes

I would appreciate help in easily converting a DateListPlot command into a DateListHistogram command. In principle, given the List, whether a plot where each point is represented by a point as versus a horizontal bar for a histogram is just a question of visual representation. I would appreciate a tip on how this can be realized in Mathematica.

Comment: Would this do the trick? `DateListPlot[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0]`

Comment: Z Ming Ma, please revisit  [your 18 questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/70345/z-ming-ma?tab=questions) and consider accepting/upvoting the answers posted. If you have not done so already please visit the page [Tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how to vote/accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `data` from chris's answer:

```
data = {{DateObject[{2016, 10, 1}, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.`], 
   10}, {DateObject[{2016, 10, 15}, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.`], 
   17}, {DateObject[{2016, 10, 30}, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.`], 
   15}, {DateObject[{2016, 11, 20}, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.`], 
   20}};
```

**1.** You can create a [`WeightedData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeightedData.html) object from `data` and use it with  [`DateHistogram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateHistogram.html):

```
wd = WeightedData @@ Transpose[data];

DateHistogram[wd, {15, "Day"}]
```

[image]

Altenatively, specify your own bin delimiters:

```
binlims = Append[ wd["InputData"], 
   DatePlus[wd["InputData"][[-1]], {1, "Month"}]];

DateHistogram[wd, {binlims}]
```

[image]

**2.** You can use [`DateListStepPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateListStepPlot.html):

```
DateListStepPlot[data, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

Use the second argument to specify the *steps*:

```
Column[DateListStepPlot[data, #, Filling -> Axis, 
    PlotLabel -> Style[#, 16], ImageSize -> Large, AspectRatio -> 1/3,
     PlotRange -> {{"Sep 1, 2016", "Dec 15, 2016"}, All}] & /@
  {Center, Left, Right}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice!  Any idea why the last bin is plotted differently in my answer?

Comment: @chris, you need to add a data point to the right with the same value as the last data point to get a similar picture when you use  `InterpolationOrder -> 0` because data is not extrapolated automatically. (I think this inconvenience  is one of the reasons for introducing `ListStepPlot` and `DateListStepPlot`).

Answer (score 3):

```
data = {{DateObject[{2016, 10, 1}, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.`], 
    10}, {DateObject[{2016, 10, 15}, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.`], 
    17}, {DateObject[{2016, 10, 30}, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.`], 
    15}, {DateObject[{2016, 11, 20}, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.`], 20}}
```

[image]

```
DateListPlot[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0, Filling -> Bottom, 
 FillingStyle -> Pink]
```

[image]

It seems to represent differently the last day though...

Comment: I accept. DateListStepPlot produces the equivalent of the histogram I seek. Thank you very much.

Comment: ZMingMa accepting involves ticking the accept tick on the left to the answer. I would suggest you accept @kglr which is a better answer.

Comment: Yes. I meant to accept Suggestion 2 which is to use DateListStepPlot as a proxy for DateListHistogram. Thanks for the reminder. Z. Ming Ma